# Making a design for a Problem

Tags: object-oriented-design

I have written many codes using OOPS and I am still to understand when is a code good enough to be accepted by experts. The thought procedure of every man is different and so is the design. My question is should I do something in particular to design my programs in such a way that they are good enough to be accepted by people.
Other thing I have also read Head First Object Oriented Design but at last I feel that the way they design the problems is much different I would have designed them.

Answer (score 2):

Code is good enough when it satisfies the customer's requirements for functionality, performance and maintainability.

That's it.  If you can accomplish those things with your approaches, more power to you.

Best practices are learned by gaining experience in coding design, and studying the design practices of others.  Over time, you will discover those practices that yield consistent results, and other practices which are ultimately unproductive.

Comment: Can I leave everything on the customer means he might not have that much knowledge and can receive what he wants even though if it is not done in good way!

Comment: Sometimes the customer just wants you to ship.  The first, buggy implementation of a product often wins in the marketplace over the perfectly-polished, but late to the market product.

Answer (score 1):

> should I do something in particular to design my programs in such a way that they are good enough to be accepted by people

I don't agree with this approach. You **shouldn't be designing your application for the sake of having some design** patterns implemented there. Design patterns are used to solve some specific type of problems/challenges that your software project is facing.

Keeping your code as simple as possible should be the best design approach. In another words, [**KISS and YAGNI**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/kiss-and-yagni.html) are the best guidelines in the design process.

As well as, [**Solid-development-principles**](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2009/02/11/solid-development-principles-in-motivational-pictures/) should be the way to improve your application code base, as needed.

Comment: Damn, I should have said KISS and YAGNI in my answer.  And SOLID.  And...

Comment: Agree, with you... SOLID principles should always be in out tool belt !